# Making a grading calculator using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Grade Calculator</title>
    
        <script>
            function doubleMe()
            {
                var number;
                var total;
                
                number = document.getElementById('txtnumber').value;
                
                number = Number(number);
                total = number * 2;
                
                console.log("number(): " + number +  " " + total);
                
                
                number = document.getElementById('txtnumber').value;
                number = parseInt(number);
                total = number * 2;
                
                console.log("parseInt(): " + number + " " + total);
                
                number = document.getElementById('txtnumber').value;
                number = parseFloat(number);    
                total = number * 2;
                
                console.log("parseFloat(): " + number + " " + total);
                
                document.getElementById('divOutput').innerHTML = total;
            }
            </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h1>Grade Calculator</h1>
        
        Term 1 Mark: <input type = 'text' id = 'txtnumber' /><br><br>
        Term 2 Mark: <input type = 'text' id = 'txtnumber' /><br><br>
        Term 3 Mark: <input type = 'text' id = 'txtnumber' /><br><br>
        Final Exam Mark: <input type = 'text' id = 'txtnumber' /><br><br>
        Term 1 Percentage: <input type = 'text' id = 'txtnumber' /><br><br>
        Term 2 Percentage: <input type = 'text' id = 'txtnumber' /><br><br>
        Term 3 Percentage: <input type = 'text' id = 'txtnumber' /><br><br>
        
        <input type = 'button' value = 'Press Me' onclick = 'doubleMe();' /><br><br>
        
        <div id = 'divOutput'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hi, I'm suppose to be making a Grading calculator where you input your scores and percentages and once you click "press me" it adds up all of your grades and gives you your final grade. But I can't seem to get to work, can someone help me out? please and thank you!

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what problems you're having? You *do* keep overwriting the value of `total` which makes it not a particularly good embodiment of what a "total" is.

Comment: Technically, in this "calculator" you're suppose to put your numerical grade for each term and the final exam. Ex; Term 1: 4 Term 2: 4 and so on.... Then it should add all these answers up and give you your final score. out of 100%

Comment: I'd start by adding them all up then.

Comment: So what is purpose of percentage you are taking as input. Also score should be out of 100 or what as it will be required for final % calculation.

Comment: Also currently you have given same id to all input fields, if you wish to have values of all in your JS you need to give separate  ID's to each input and sum them up. Giving same id won't auto sum up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some tweaks into your code where it will take input of Term 1,Term  2, Term 3 & Final Term marks. And will return sum & percentage of them considering marks for each term is out of 100.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Grade Calculator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Grade Calculator</h1>
    Term 1 Mark: <input type="text" id="txtnumber1" /><br /><br />
    Term 2 Mark: <input type="text" id="txtnumber2" /><br /><br />
    Term 3 Mark: <input type="text" id="txtnumber3" /><br /><br />
    Final Exam Mark: <input type="text" id="txtnumber4" /><br /><br />
    Term 1 Percentage: <input type="text" id="txtnumber5" /><br /><br />
    Term 2 Percentage: <input type="text" id="txtnumber6" /><br /><br />
    Term 3 Percentage: <input type="text" id="txtnumber7" /><br /><br />
    <input type="button" value="Press Me" onclick="percentage();" /><br /><br />
    <div id="divOutpuTotal"></div>
    <div id="divOutputPercentage"></div>

    <script>
      function percentage() {
        var total;
        var total =
          Number(document.getElementById("txtnumber1").value) +
          Number(document.getElementById("txtnumber2").value) +
          Number(document.getElementById("txtnumber3").value) +
          Number(document.getElementById("txtnumber4").value);
        document.getElementById("divOutpuTotal").innerHTML = total;
        document.getElementById("divOutputPercentage").innerHTML = total / 4;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can improve logic more based on your specific requirement.